# ASP. NET C# Web Application Performance Issues

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, web

I have an ASPX page with 40 ++ Drop Down List in a table generated from back-end C# code as shown: 
[Drop Down Lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4dVf.png)

These drop down list can be searchable with the help  3rd party jQuery below:

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery.searchabledropdown-1.0.8.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Everything working fine except when the page is loaded it is very slow which took about 20 to 30 seconds.

Any advice guys? Is there any other way around or other better recommendation on the wild search?

Thanks...

This is the summary of the back end code:

```
//This chunk build the drop down list in the table
for (int y = 1; y <= DETAIL_ROW; y++)
{
     DropDownList InternalOrderDDL = new DropDownList();
     InternalOrderDDL.ID = "InternalOrderDDL" + y.ToString();
     InternalOrderDDL.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
     InternalOrderDDL.Attributes.Add("onfocus",   "ChangeDropDownWidth(this);");
     InternalOrderDDL.Attributes.Add("onblur", "ResetDropDownWidth(this);");

     HtmlTableCell InternalOrderCell = new HtmlTableCell();
     InternalOrderCell.Controls.Add(InternalOrderDDL);

     NewRow.Cells.Add(InternalOrderCell);
     DetailTable.Rows.Add(NewRow);
}

//This chunk of code populate the Drop Down List 
DataTable InternalOrderDT = new DataTable();

using (SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING))
{
    SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("spActiveInternalOrderRetrieveListByCompany", Conn);
    Cmd.CommandTimeout = 0; 
    Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    Cmd.Parameters.Add("CompanyID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = companyID;
    Conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader Dr = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
    InternalOrderDT.Load(Dr);
    Conn.Close();
}

for (int y = 1; y <= DETAIL_ROW; y++)
{
    DropDownList InternalOrderDDL = DetailTable.FindControl("InternalOrderDDL" + y.ToString()) as DropDownList;
    InternalOrderDDL.DataTextField = "InternalOrderName";
    InternalOrderDDL.DataValueField = "InternalOrderID";
    InternalOrderDDL.DataSource = InternalOrderDT;
    InternalOrderDDL.DataBind();
    InternalOrderDDL.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--", ""));

}
```

Comment: Can you please put up back end code.

Comment: Also try to profile your database calls

Comment: @NayanKatkani I had edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

My tip is to cache data. Check which of the 40 drop down list can be cached, from data you won't need to get data from the database, but using from the cache. It will save you some seconds and reduce the amount of time spent with the rendering. Also check the possibility of using OutputCache.

Another thing that may worth is check the database performance. Check if there's some old data that could be archived. Also check if there's any missing index and if the queries are returning only the data you need, rather than all the fields from the table.